# Как трансформировать PyQt6 приложение в .exe и .app?

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, pyinstaller, pyqt6

Я создал своё приложение на *Python* при помощи **`PyQt6`**.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы оно запускалось на *Windows* и *Mac OS*, на которых не установлен *Python*?

Comment: Собрать приложения через утилиты для этого. Если утилиты не включают в приложения библиотеки/dll, то добавить их в папку с приложениями. В любом случае, нужны будут библиотеки Qt для windows и macos

Comment: и привет хеллоу ворд на 250 мегабайт)

Comment: Кажется, что `pyinstaller` еще не поддерживает `PyQt6`

Answer (score 2):

#### Вы можете использовать pyinstaller для конвертации *.py файла в *.exe

Сначала, вам нужно установить **pyinstaller**. Чтобы это сделать, выполните следующую команду в терминале:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Чтобы конвертировать ваш файл, просто выполните следущую команду в терминале:

```
pyinstaller yourprogram.py
```

В рабочей директории появится папка dist с исполняемым ***.exe** файлом внутри.

Также, вы можете ознакомиться с более подробной версией описания [по этой ссылке](https://www.pyinstaller.org).